# Word documents generation in web app using Eclipse BIRT Report Engine

Tags: java, eclipse, ms-word, birt

Is it possible to generate word documents (*.doc) in java web application using Eclipse BIRT (Report Engine)? I want .rptdesign to be an input file in generating process. I could not find any example or tutorial.

What would you recommend as an alternative solution. As far as I know Jasper Reports allow only RTF format generation.

Thank you for your answer/explaination

Comment: I have developed this as a quick alternative http://lowcoupling.com/post/62918887435/dono-a-document-notation-to-generate-ms-word-documents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, BIRT can generate a report in HTML, Postscript, PDF, Excel, and Word out of the box.

http://wiki.eclipse.org/BIRT/FAQ/Output_Formats

Answer (score 0):

Other alternatives include [Docmosis](http://www.docmosis.com) and [JODReports](http://jodreports.sourceforge.net/).  The Docmosis website has an online demo where you can get a feel for it.

Comment: hi, just to mention my homemade tool http://lowcoupling.com/post/62918887435/dono-a-document-notation-to-generate-ms-word-documents